# jQuery align table (number of rows/cells) based on screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabular

I have a table like this (8 cells only for illustrative purposes, may be more or less):

```
[1] [2] [3] [4]
[5] [6] [7] [8]
```

Each item in each cell is roughly 450px wide, so they fit comfortably next to each other on a 1920x1200 screen (which, incidentially, is mine). However, I need this configuration to change automatically and align the best possible way in case somebody with a smaller (or wider) screen resolution comes along, or resizes the browser window.

So, for 1024x768 it would be:

```
[1] [2]
[3] [4]
(etc)
```

and for 2560x1600 it would be:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
[6] [7] [8] [9] [10]
(etc)
```

How can I do something like this - maybe with jQuery or CSS?

Comment: You might have a look at how google does it - if you check their image search source you'll see that that's what they do. While their JS is not the most readable, you might be able to get something out of it with a JS debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a table use an unordered list. Ensure that the width of the unordered list itself (or perhaps its container) is a percentage width (it will scale to the size of the browser window). Float each of the `<li>` elements and specify a width if you want them equal size. The browser will do the rest for you.

Example:

```
HTML:
<ul id="mydata">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

CSS:
ul#mydata { width: 90%; }
  ul#mydata li { width: 450px; float: left; } /* Don't *have* to specify width */
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched and just found by myself

Don't use "table", use "div, with style attribute set to "float: left" for each div... and set width and height of your blocks, it will work, like this :

```
<div style=\"width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left\">CONTENT</div>
<div style=\"width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left\">CONTENT</div>
<div style=\"width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left\">CONTENT</div>
<div style=\"width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left\">CONTENT</div>
<div style=\"width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left\">CONTENT</div>
<div style=\"width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left\">CONTENT</div>
```

And try to resize your page for example.

Hope it will helps someone other.

Cerdan